# Fetch more than 200 sharedviews in to rally ext combo box

Tags: javascript, extjs, rally, code-rally

I am working on developing a custom rally report which has got several views - these views sit in the combo box - to my surprise, I have noticed that on the page load only 200 are retrieved but I have 300 views for this report. I haven't got any help from the documentation. 
The following is what I am trying

```
 getSharedViewConfig() {
            return {
                ptype: 'rallygridboardsharedviewcontrol',
                sharedViewConfig: {
                    enableUrlSharing: this.isFullPageApp !== false,
                    stateful: true,
                    width: 300,
                    pageSize: 200,
                    limit: Infinity,
                    queryMode: 'remote',
                    stateId: this.getContext().getScopedStateId('views'),
                    stateEvents: ['select', 'beforedestroy'],
                    suppressViewNotFoundNotification: this._suppressViewNotFoundNotification,
                    emptyText: 'Select or Add Saved View...',
                    additionalFilters: [this.piTypePicker.getCurrentViewFilter()],
                    autoExpand: true,
                    defaultViews: _.map(this._getDefaultViews(), (view) => {
                        Ext.apply(view, {
                            Value: Ext.JSON.encode(view.Value, true)
                        });
                        return view;
                    }, this)
                },

            };
        },
```

How can I retrieve the rest of the views? When I set pagesize: 200 I am able to see the pagination bar at the bottom but this seems to be bombing as soon as I click the next arrow

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, what if you just set the page size to 2000?  WSAPI supports 2000 as a max.  The UX of having that many items in a dropdown are obviously not ideal, but it might get you what you need here...

Comment: I have tried doing the same - that is increasing the pageSize to 2000, it gives me the pagination - as soon as I click on next - it doesn't apply the filters and fetches some unlimited items in to the combobox.

Comment: I need to look into it a bit more.  The pageSize config is not actually a recognized config parameter, so it's being ignored...

Answer (score 0):

No it doesn't work that way for me - the pagination is bringing in all the items - no filters are adhering the rule and when I click the right arrow to render the page 2 I see an increase in pagination size form 6 to some 1321.

Thanks
Sai[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gyKMQ.png)